# Tweaking the syncing between editor and viewer

Tags: forward-inverse-search, textmate

I've been using TextMate and Skim for a while and they work great.
For some reason though, whenever I compile the `tex` code Skim opens up the `pdf` but always manages to get the line wrong.

What I mean is, if I am currently at some line on my `tex` code, the viewer will open, it will display a red dot in the right spot, but will scroll up half a page or so.

It should be a problem of forward searching, so it's to do with TextMate's settings, or possibly there is some option I could pass to the LaTeX compiler to tell him to sync differently.

any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to have noticed this question only now: are you perhaps using XeLaTeX?

Comment: sorry for having seen your comment only now ;) nope, good ol' pdflatex. Could the fact that I keep my files in a dropbox folder be relevant?

Comment: @donkeykong No, I doubt it. What version of pdfTeX are you using (for example, what does `pdftex --version` say)?